# ArcGIS Pro Wait Cursor in C# - Mouse Cursor Class

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, c#

It was very easy to set a wait cursor for an add-in tool in ArcGIS for Desktop.
It looked like this:

```
        ESRI.ArcGIS.Framework.IMouseCursor appCursor = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Framework.MouseCursorClass();
        // wait cursor
        appCursor.SetCursor(2);
        // normal cursor
        appCursor.SetCursor(1);
```

I cannot figure out how to do it in Pro. How to set a wait cursor in Pro?

Answer (score 1):

The MapExploration Snippets in the ArcGIS Pro SDK documentation includes this [sample](https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-pro-sdk/wiki/ProSnippets-MapExploration#change-the-cursor-of-a-tool) to change the cursor of a tool

```
internal class CustomMapTool : MapTool
{
  public CustomMapTool()
  {
    IsSketchTool = true;
    SketchType = SketchGeometryType.Rectangle;
    SketchOutputMode = SketchOutputMode.Map;
    //A custom cursor file as an embedded resource
    var cursorEmbeddedResource = new Cursor(new MemoryStream(MapExploration.Resource1.red_cursor));
    //A built in system cursor
    var systemCursor = System.Windows.Input.Cursors.ArrowCD;
    //Set the "CustomMapTool's" Cursor property to either one of the cursors defined above
    Cursor = cursorEmbeddedResource;
    //or
    Cursor = systemCursor;
  }
```

Comment: I have implemented the code from this sample, but to no effect.  My cursor is not changing when I click my map tool.  I am just getting the default hand pointer cursor and not my custom cursor that I have saved into my solution as an embedded resource.  Any thoughts as to what I might be doing wrong?